# How do I convert a nested list to dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-binding

I webscrape an url and I get a nested list. In the next step I want to convert this to a dataframe. But my solution doesn't work. I think the problem is that the listelemts have names and I can't delete it before converting.  Hope you have some hints.

```
require(tidyverse)
require(rvest)

#create a list, which looks like this what I get after webscrape ( my code for scraping is at the end)
item1 <- data.frame(id_course1 = c("id_course1", "id_course1"),
                    course1 = c("participants", 15),
                    course1 = c("mark1", 1),
                    course1 = c("mark2", 2),
                    course1 = c("mark3", 3),
                    course1 = c("mark4", 4),
                    course1 = c("mark5", 5))
item2 <- data.frame(id_course2 = c("id_course2", "id_course2"),
                    course2 = c("participants", 30),
                    course2 = c("mark1", 10),
                    course2 = c("mark2", 8),
                    course2 = c("mark3", 6),
                    course2 = c("mark4", 4),
                    course2 = c("mark5", 2))
item3 <- data.frame(id_course3 = c("id_course3", "id_course3"),
                    course3 = c("participants", 15),
                    course3 = c("mark1", 2),
                    course3 = c("mark2", 4),
                    course3 = c("mark3", 5),
                    course3 = c("mark4", 3),
                    course3 = c("mark5", 1))
my.list <- list(item1, item2, item3)

#create dataframe, but the result is not what I want
require(data.table)
data.table::rbindlist(my.list, fill=TRUE)
dplyr::bind_rows(my.list)
dplyr::bind_rows(unname(my.list))

# try to use only the second row of the table, but the result is not what I want
do.call("cbind", lapply(my.list, "[[", 2) )
do.call("rbind", lapply(my.list, "[[", 2) )
lapply(my.list, "[[", 2) %>% dplyr::bind_rows

#at the end I want a table that looks like this
df_what_i_want <- data.frame(t(data.frame(c("id_course1", 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ),
                                        c("id_course2", 30, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2 ),
                                        c("id_course3", 15, 2, 4, 5, 3, 1 ))))
rownames(df_what_i_want) <- NULL
colnames(df_what_i_want) <- c("id_course1", "participants", "mark1", "mark2", "mark3", "mark4", "mark5" )


# scrape the website
url <- "https://www.fernuni-hagen.de/wirtschaftswissenschaft/studium/klausurstatistik.shtml"
courses_list <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes("li") %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: The comments in your code suggests that the code runs without error but doesn't produce the desired result.  But you don't tell us what the desired result actually is.  How can we help you when we don't have the information we need?

Comment: When I run a code like dplyr::bind_rows(my.list), than it doesn't bind row by row. In the dataframe I have Table1 and right under Table1 I have Table2 and so on the rest is filled with NA. It is hard to describe for me and easier to execute the minimalexample to see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this would also do

```
library(janitor)
library(tidyverse)
map_dfr(my.list, ~(as.data.frame(.) %>% janitor::row_to_names(1) %>% setNames(my.list[[1]][1,])))

  id_course1 participants mark1 mark2 mark3 mark4 mark5
1 id_course1           15     1     2     3     4     5
2 id_course2           30    10     8     6     4     2
3 id_course3           15     2     4     5     3     1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better if you correct the code while scraping itself. Try this :

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.fernuni-hagen.de/wirtschaftswissenschaft/studium/klausurstatistik.shtml"

read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes("li") %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  head %>% #remove this later
  html_table(fill = TRUE)  %>%
  purrr::map_df(~.x %>% setNames(.[1, ]) %>% slice(-1)) -> result

result
```

Comment: When I run the script, then there are no content in the table. Nice to see, that I can cut every 1st row with slice(-1) :-)